# Agrupar cliques em botão "mais" e "menos" para fazer menos requisições seguidas

Tags: jquery, ajax

Num site tenho um botao "mais" e "menos" para alterar a quantidade de um item no carrinho, só que o item é atualizado aose dar um clique. Se o cliente clicar 10 vezes seguidas, são feitas 10 requisições,e o servidor demora para executar todos os processos e então dá timeout.
Preciso poder clicar quantas vezes quiser no botão para aumentar a quantidade, e daí, quando eu parar de clicar, depois de 2 segundos, atualizar os valores, fazendo somente uma requisição.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: É realmente necessário fazer requisições ao servidor somente para modificar quantidade de um produto? Não pode obter os dados para cálculo na própria página html, usando javascript?

Comment: Não poderia ser uma coisa mai simples, tipo isso: [Exemplo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/kumyaj8g/), afinal, para que fazer requisição no servidor, se você pode limitar a quantidade de itens num input do tipo number?

Comment: Daniel Omine e Ivan Ferrer, entrem no carrinho e vejam e testem essa funcionalidade clicando varias vezes no borao de aumentar e diminiuir quantidade desses sites mickey.com.br e vestindoamesa.com.br, me diz em ql deles a sua experiencia como usuario é melhor.. n q esteja ruim do jeito q esta, mas tem q ter capricho.. eu n guardo os dados do carrinho no cookie, guardo no banco, pois meu sistema tem uma parte de compras no abandono ou desistencia, onde o lojista pode enviar um email para o cliente avisando sobre a compra..

Comment: @Daniel Omine msg d cima

Comment: @Ivan Ferrer msg acima

Comment: @GregoryIyama, volto na mesma questão, você não precisa gravar isso no banco, a experiência foi melhor no www.mickey.com.br, bem mais rápido, embora quando você dá um refresh, ele não mantém a quantidade, porém isso poderia ser resolvido através de `setTimeout()` + `sessionStorage` ou `localStorage`. ou `session` mesmo do PHP. Abandono e desistência podem ser gravados quando expira a sessão.

Comment: Você não precisa gravar desistência a cada click... grava na sessão os itens que ele pegou... sempre. E a cada minuto, salva no banco os itens da lista, dá pra fazer isso de maneira assíncrona, como também dá pra fazer isso de outras maneiras como cron, etc... é melhor do que na experiência de click do usuário.

Comment: @GregoryIyama, você sabe que dá pra monitorar a página que está sendo acessada em `realtime` quando você tem um usuário conectado, é como funcionam os chats. Dá pra fazer isso na tela do carrinho também, e quando a tela fechar, dá também para você saber que o usuário abandonou. Só uma outra opção.

Answer (score 0):

**Olha... não sou muito experiente... código feio mas funcional. Talvez encontre algum bug. 
Agradeço quem der alguma dica também.**

```js
var cont = 0;
    
    $("#aumentaQuantidade").click(function() {
        cont = 0;
        setTimeout("contarTempo()", 1000);
    });

    $("#diminuirQuantidade").click(function() {
        cont = 0;
        setTimeout("contarTempo()", 1000);
    });
    
    function contar() {
        cont++;
    }

    function contarTempo() {                
        $('body').append(cont);
        if (cont == 2)
        {
            minhaRequisicaoAjax();
            cont = -1;
        }
        
        if (cont != -1)
        {
            setTimeout("contar()", 1000);
        }
    }
    function minhaRequisicaoAjax() {
        // seu código de requisição ...        
        alert("requisição ajax . . . ");
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Página Teste</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>    
 </head>
 <body>
      <input type="button" id="aumentaQuantidade" value="+"/>
      <input type="button" id="aumentaQuantidade" value="-"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Entretanto você poderia fazer como eles disseram. Mas está aí o que você questionou.**

Comment: muito obrigado msm pelo seu codigo! eu tava ia testar ele aqui qnd recebi a ajuda d um amigo e rolou. mas obrigado msm pela forca!!
se quisr r como ficou segue abaixo:

var cartUpdate; 


function cartUpdateStartTimer( id ) {
    cartUpdate = setTimeout(function(){ carrinho_atualiza_item(id) }, 1000);
}
function cartUpdateStopTimer(){
 clearTimeout(cartUpdate);
}
function carrinho_item_mais( id, valor_unit ){
 
 cartUpdateStopTimer();
 
 var qtd = $('#qtd-item-'+id).val();
 
 qtd++;
 qtd = ( qtd >= 99 ) ? 99 : qtd;
 $('#qtd-item-'+id).attr('value',qtd);

 cartUpdateStartTimer( id );
 
}

Comment: uma função começa a contagem e a outra para
ai qnd o cara clica no mais, cancela a contagem, adiciona 1 item, e comca a contagem, se o cara clicar novamente ele volta a função, cancela a contagem e incrementa mais um, se ele para d clicar a contagem continua, se der o tempo ele processa a informação e atualiza a pagina c a função q ta dentro do cartUpdateStartTimer

ganhei mt em performance e UX


abracao!!!

Comment: Que bom que consegui ajudá-lo. Infelizmente não tive tempo para comentar melhor ou nomear melhor as functions. Abraço!